# Normal usb device recognized, android phone not

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox

I tried the following virtualbox 5

HOST: win 8.1

guest: lubuntu 14.04

I installed android sdk into `/root/Android`

(android studio installer did that)

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

I added the android device to the usb devices

[image]

the android does NOT show up any more in windows, but as virtualbox usb device.

It does not show up when hovering the usb icon of virtualbox, as connected usb though:

[image]

`"No USB devices attached"`

when I change the usb device to soemthing else, it does show attached.

`sudo -i`

`adb devices`

lists empty list

`lsusb`

lists

`root@osboxes:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

which is the same as when I have no usb/android connected

what am I missing?

do i have to install some drivers for my lubuntu guest?

it seems to me normal usb devices get recognized but my phone.

developer options usb debugging is enabled on my phone when i connect it.
I tried using USB 2 as well... at least the setting, actual USB 2 ports I don't have.

Comment: Is it visible to host OS? Try Samsung and Google USB drivers first for your WIndows OS.

Comment: it is visible to my host OS, then I start my VM and it disappears, as it should if I understand correctly.

Comment: Try switching to USB 2.0 mode and plugging it into physical USB 2.0 port -  Windows 8.1 has allergy on 3.0

Comment: i updated my question, I don't have physical USB 2 and i tried switching it to usb 2 mode as well

Comment: I guess you are doomed then.

Comment: how comes ALL usb devices get recognized on the usb 3 ports, but my bloody android phone?

Comment: I spent 2 month struggling to get steady adb connection with Nexus 7 and Samsung Note 3 in Windows 8.1. Ended up installing Windows 7.

Comment: Try switching PTP <-> MTP back and forth while in lubuntu

Comment: OK, I'll put it as an answer, in case someone gets caught on the same trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching PTP <-> MTP in Android USB options back and forth while in Lubuntu .

Comment: that was it. It was on MTP the whole time because I could not find the USB option (it appears only when connecting the USB, then in the notification bar!!! not settings... in the notification bar is the setting. In my galaxy S3 T999 at least)